# Centred text in reledmac

Tags: horizontal-alignment, reledmac

Please consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia,fontspec,xunicode}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={16cm, 22cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[noresetlinenumannotation, series={A}, noend,noeledsec,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\newcommand{\bv}[1]{\linenumannotation{#1}}
\makeatletter
\Xwraplinenumannotation{\@firstofone}
\renewcommand{\linenumrep}[1]{}
\makeatother
\Xnoidenticallinenumannotation
\fnpos{critical-familiar}
\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
\end{center}
\vspace{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter*{}
   \beginnumbering
  \linenummargin{inner}
  \pstart
  \noindent
\begin{center}
    \ledouternote{A2\textit{r}}Here beginneth the story of my life as told to you by the most righteous, most learned fellow of the West Midlands\\
  \textsc{Dr Lorem Ipsum}.\\
  \end{center}
  \pend 
  \endnumbering
  \firstlinenum{1}
  \linenumincrement{1}
  \beginnumbering
  \linenummargin{inner}
  \pstart
    \bv{1}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Et leo duis ut diam. Viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris. Ac feugiat sed \edtext{lectus}{\Afootnote{lectulus}} vestibulum mattis. Eget sit amet tellus cras adipiscing. Nec dui nunc mattis enim ut. Tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales\ledouternote{A2\textit{v}}. Semper feugiat nibh sed pulvinar proin gravida hendrerit. Ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis eleifend quam. Vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim \edtext{sodales}{\Afootnote{sodalis}} ut. Ullamcorper malesuada proin libero nunc. Nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris a diam. Orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc.

\bv{2}Tempus quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et. Netus et malesuada fames ac turpis. Euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate odio ut. Ut sem nulla pharetra diam sit amet. Sed libero enim sed faucibus turpis in eu. Interdum consectetur libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt. Elementum nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing. Eget mi proin sed libero enim. Sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem integer vitae justo. Venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. Pellentesque. 
    \pend
    \endnumbering
    \end{document}
```

For some reasons, whenever I center some text in the `reledmac` environment, the paragraph acts a bit quirky. In this case, I cannot display the side note and the spacing is uneven. Do you know why? Thank you! [image: MWE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The `\centering` commands (call by the `center` environnement) redefine `\\`
2. The redefinition of this `\\` include some insertion of `\vspace`
3. Reledmac presume that there is not `\vspace` inside a `\pstart`...`\pend`, and that each line have the same height.
4. That why you get something weird.
5. You should change paragraph instead of using `\\`
6. Also `center` environnement add vertical space, which is problematic inside a `\pstart`.  So use `\centering` instead.

So :

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia,fontspec,xunicode}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={16cm, 22cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[noresetlinenumannotation, series={A}, noend,noeledsec,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\newcommand{\bv}[1]{\linenumannotation{#1}}
\makeatletter
\Xwraplinenumannotation{\@firstofone}
\renewcommand{\linenumrep}[1]{}
\makeatother
\Xnoidenticallinenumannotation
\fnpos{critical-familiar}
\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
\end{center}
\vspace{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter*{}
   \beginnumbering
  \linenummargin{inner}
  \pstart
  \noindent
  \centering
    \ledouternote{A2\textit{r}}Here beginneth the story of my life as told to you by the most righteous, most learned fellow of the West Midlands

  \textsc{Dr Lorem Ipsum}.
  \pend
  \endnumbering
  \firstlinenum{1}
  \linenumincrement{1}
  \beginnumbering
  \linenummargin{inner}
  \pstart
    \bv{1}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Et leo duis ut diam. Viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris. Ac feugiat sed \edtext{lectus}{\Afootnote{lectulus}} vestibulum mattis. Eget sit amet tellus cras adipiscing. Nec dui nunc mattis enim ut. Tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales\ledouternote{A2\textit{v}}. Semper feugiat nibh sed pulvinar proin gravida hendrerit. Ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis eleifend quam. Vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim \edtext{sodales}{\Afootnote{sodalis}} ut. Ullamcorper malesuada proin libero nunc. Nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris a diam. Orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc.

\bv{2}Tempus quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et. Netus et malesuada fames ac turpis. Euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate odio ut. Ut sem nulla pharetra diam sit amet. Sed libero enim sed faucibus turpis in eu. Interdum consectetur libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt. Elementum nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing. Eget mi proin sed libero enim. Sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem integer vitae justo. Venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. Pellentesque.
    \pend
    \endnumbering
    \end{document}
```

ps : next time, please provide a MWE which does not need special font.

Comment: Thank you, @Maïeul, that was what I was looking for

Comment: On second thought, I don't think the solution you suggested works for me for the following reasons: a) I need a new line after "most learned" and the spacing becomes quirky again if I use the `\pstart` `\pend` options; b) I want a blank space before and after the "Dr Lorem Ipsum" line.

Comment: you can separate them in different pstart / pend, and use optional argument of pstart/pend to insert vertical space.